# Unterschied zwischen "vorhersagen" und "vorhersehen"

Tags: meaning

ich habe mehrmals versucht, den Unterschied zwischen "vorhersagen" und "vorhersehen" zu verstehen.

Kann jemand bitte es klären?

Vielen Dank,
Daniele

Comment: Hmm, der Unterschied ist sehr subtil und möglicherweise abhängig vom Kontext.

Answer (score 3):

Ich sehe da große Unterschiede:

1) etwas vorhersagen:  im Voraus sagen, wie etwas verlaufen, ausgehen wird

2) etwas vorhersehen: im Voraus erkennen, wissen, wie etwas verlaufen, ausgehen wird

Im zweiten Fall ist es völlig unwichtig, ob man es überhaupt jemandem mitteilt (sagt).

Vor allem aus späterer Betrachtung, wird der Unterschied deutlich:

Er hat es vorhergesehen (und richtig/falsch reagiert).

aber:

Er hat es vorausgesagt (, sodass andere richtig/falsch reagieren konnten).

Comment: Danke für Euere Antworten. Welcher Verb bedeutet nicht nur eine Prophezeiung sondern auch eine Überlegung zu was man in der Zukunft gesehen hat?
So weit ich verstanden habe, ist "vorhersagen". Habe ich es gut verstanden? Danke
Vielen Dank,

Comment: @Daniele Kannst du noch mehr zum Kontext sagen? "Überlege, was man in der Zukunft gesehen hat" klingt sehr esoterisch und die korrekte Benennung scheint mir sehr vom Kontext abhängig zu sein.

Answer (score 2):

*vorhersagen* impliziert, dass eine definite Aussage zu einem zukünftigen Ereignis gemacht wird, während *vorhersehen* lediglich die Möglichkeit des eventuell eintretenden Ereignisses in Aussicht stellt.

Man sollte also eine *Vorhersage* als die *stärkere* Variante im Gegensatz zu einer *Vorhersehung* interpretieren.

Bitte frage nicht weiter, was das für Metereologen und deren Wetter- *Vorhersage* bedeutet.

Answer (score 2):

Der Unterschied entspricht demjenigen zwischen `wissen` und `sagen`. Um etwas Sinnvolles sagen zu können, muss man das nötige Wissen haben. Wenn Du also etwas `vorhergesehen` hast, kannst Du es `vorhersagen`. Alternativ kannst Du schweigen und später - nachdem das Unglück eingetreten ist - behaupten:

> Das hätte ich Dir auch gleich vorhersagen können!